# Change Font in Scrivener

Tags: software, scrivener

How can I change the font in Scrivener's interface? I don't care for the current one and I would like to change it to  Times New Roman.

Comment: This question has been answered [countless times](https://www.google.com/search?q=change+font+in+scrivener) on the internet.

Comment: @what he is asking about changing the font of the application interface, not the default font in the editor. Your addition to my answer was incorrect as well.

Comment: @Lew I don't understand the question that way. We'll see whether Zbigniew will accept your answer or clarify their question.

Comment: @what you might be right and the language barrier did not let the correct preposition go through: "in the interface" I read as "of the interface"; I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the font of the application interface in the **Windows** version of the application:

> Tools > Options > Appearance > Fonts

In the **Mac** version:

> Scrivener > Preferences... > Appearance

For changing the default font and other editor's options please refer to the link in the @what's comment to your question.

Comment: I don't see the Windows version in principal tools bar.

Comment: I edited the answer for clarity